# Using a Field Parameter in a Measure

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have written the below DAX function:

```
Slicer_Filter =
VAR Virtual =
SELECTCOLUMNS (
        SUMMARIZE ( 'X-Parameter', 'X-Parameter'[X-Parameter], 'X-Parameter'[X-Parameter Fields] ),
        "Sales", [Count_EID]
    )
VAR MINVALUE = MINX(Virtual, [Sales])
VAR MAXVALUE = MAXX(Virtual, [Sales])
VAR CURRENTSLICERVALUE = SELECTEDVALUE('EID_Count_Parameter'[EID_Count_Parameter])
RETURN
IF(
    CURRENTSLICERVALUE>=MINVALUE && CURRENTSLICERVALUE <=MAXVALUE,
    1,
    0
)
```

This is to be used on a slicer which is created using Numeric Field Parameter.
Now i am able to use this properly except the slicer shows max value in MIN value box (Slicer is between slicer.)
X-Parameter is a Field parameter.

How can we solve for this? I cant share the pbix file but if there is anything more information requried please let me know.

Comment: What do you mean by "slicer shows max value in MIN value box"? Can you update the question with a snip so we can see? Does it fix it self when you click on the `Clear selection` button at the top-right of the slicer?